# How I edit files in Program Files folder?

Tags: windows-8.1

I am the sole user of my system, also my user account has Admin powers, and for most power I can do anything I want...

Except,  edit files in Program Files or Program Files(x86) folders, and I have LOTS of apps and games that require manual editing of configuration files, also I like to program, and to mod games, and also can't edit files there.

My "solution" so far is just not install anything on those folders, also workaround by editing files elsewhere and pasting them on the target later.

These both have problems: one, lots of stuff are already on those folders, the second problem is that is lots of work to copy and paste files all over the place every time I need a tiny little change.

So how I change Program Files folders (both of them) to just let me do whatever I want?

Bonus: How I do that in a way that applications also have full access? Many games break when installed on Program Files, Steam and GOG forums are full of "solutions" that involve just not installing games there, because when you do, they break, because of silly permissions.

Comment: I have no problems modifying any file in that folder, that isn't a protected folder, it shouldn't be

Comment: Just bumping this... because I STILL need help with this.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than opening up permissions to let you do whatever you want, what you need to do is open an administrator-level explorer window and programs:

To open an administrator-level Windows Explorer window:

1. Search for `cmd.exe`, right-click on it, and select `Run as Administrator`.
2. Type `cd "C:\Program Files"`
3. Type `start .`

To edit a plaintext file (i.e. a file that can be edited with notepad) do this:

1. Search for `cmd.exe`, right-click on it, and select `Run as Administrator`.
2. Type `cd "C:\Program Files\[directory of file to be edited]"`
3. Type `notepad [filename]`

Alternatively, follow these instructions (credit to [WikiHow](http://www.wikihow.com/Add-an-%22Open-With-Notepad-As-Administrator%22-Shortcut-to-the-Context-Menu-in-Windows-7-and-Windows-Vista) - with some changes):

1. Open notepad.
2. Copy and paste this code into notepad:

> [version]
>   signature="$CHICAGO$"
>   
>   [NotepadAsAdminInstall]
>   CopyFiles = NotepadAsAdmin.Files.Inf
>   AddReg    = NotepadAsAdmin.AddReg
>   
>   [DefaultInstall]
>   CopyFiles = NotepadAsAdmin.Files.Inf
>   AddReg    = NotepadAsAdmin.AddReg
>   
>   [DefaultUnInstall]
>   DelFiles  = NotepadAsAdmin.Files.Inf
>   DelReg    = NotepadAsAdmin.DelReg
>   
>   [SourceDisksNames]
>   55="Notepad as Admin","",1
>   
>   [SourceDisksFiles]
>   NotepadAsAdmin.INF=55
>   
>   [DestinationDirs]
>   NotepadAsAdmin.Files.Inf = 17
>   
>   [NotepadAsAdmin.Files.Inf]
>   NotepadAsAdmin.INF
>   
>   [NotepadAsAdmin.AddReg]
>   HKLM,%UDHERE%,DisplayName,,"%NotepadAsAdminName%"
>   HKLM,%UDHERE%,UninstallString,,"rundll32.exe syssetup.dll,SetupInfObjectInstallAction DefaultUninstall 132 %17%\NotepadAsAdmin.inf"
>   HKCR,*\Shell\runas,,,"%NotepadAsAdminAccel%"
>
>   HKCR,*\Shell\runas\command,,,"%11%\notepad.exe ""%1"""
>   
>   [NotepadAsAdmin.DelReg]
>   HKLM,%UDHERE%
>   HKCR,Directory\Shell\runas
>   HKCR,Drive\Shell\runas
>   
>   [Strings]
>   NotepadAsAdminName="Notepad as Admin PowerToy (Uninstall)"
>   NotepadAsAdminAccel="Open with Notepad as Administrator"
>   UDHERE="Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\NotepadAsAdmin"

3. In notepad, go to `File` -> `Save As...` and select `All files`.  Save to the desktop as `NotepadAsAdmin.inf`.
4. Close notepad.
5. Right-click on `NotepadAsAdmin.inf` on the desktop, and select `Install` from the context menu.
6. You should now be able to select any file anywhere, right-click it, and select `Open with Notepad as Administrator from the context menu.

This method was said to work with Windows Vista and 7, but I don't know if it will work with 8, 8.1, but I have tested it on Windows 10, so I assume it will work with 8 and 8.1.  Alternatively, you can download a pre-made installer for this (provided through my [DropBox](https://db.tt/CTUrE5tR)) [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0n6kfs94h23x5vm/NotepadAsAdmin.inf?dl=0).  You do not need [DropBox](https://db.tt/CTUrE5tR) to download this file.

Comment: I tried the `start .` trick in Windows 7, and it didn't work.  Yes, it started a Windows Explorer window, but it wasn't privileged.

Comment: odd.  Try the notepad trick.

Comment: That one worked.

Comment: Awesome.  If this worked, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: I was talking to @speeder

Comment: This only works for stuff I can edit with notepad, I made a mistake today and forgot about this, and installe a new app on program files, and I needed to switch around some of its files... and couldn't.

Now I am having to use a third party uninstaller to scrub it out. so I can't accept the answer, sorry.

Comment: This (the answer here) seems like a lot of trouble to go to when you can just right-click on a shortcut to Notepad (or Explorer, or Command prompt) and select "Run as administrator".